# Angular populate from JSON through httpd and then choose selected

Tags: angularjs, json, ajax

I'm fairly new to Angular and i'm trying to do something quite simple. I want to populate a dropdown box and have the selected value from database as selected option. Here is my dropdown code.

```
<select ng-options="option.fname+' '+option.lname for option in students track by option.id"
               class="form-control"
               name="studentId"
               ng-model="selectedStudent"
               id="studentId"
               ng-change="loadStudent()"
               >
               <option value="">Please choose a student</option>
           </select>
```

Now, in my module and the controller, i have this code which populates the dropdown and i can see the options (student.id, student.fname , student.lname):

```
$scope.students = {};
$scope.selectedStudent = null;
$scope.populateStudents = function() {
    $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax/getStudents',
            data: { teacherId: 0 }
        }).success(function (result) {
        $scope.students = result;
        $scope.selectedStudent = 4;
        });
}
```

This runs i guess on page load as i have this :

Then on the above script and after the $scope.students is loaded, i write 
      `$scope.selectedStudent = 4;` which I want to preselect the student with student.id = 4.

What happens though is that the default 
`<option value="">Please choose a student</option> is becoming <option value="" select="selected">Please choose a student</option>` instead of the student with id 4.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you calling your `populateStudents` method ?

Comment: Dear @CamiloR, thank your your answer. Yes i use it on ng-init and it is populating fine.

Comment: Can you provide a plunker to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: Dear @JoelCDoyle your answer you provided 10 minutes ago was the working one. I just wasnt sure if i have to loop through the object results and set the selected object instead of just a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `ngOptions` with an array of complex objects, you must use an identical complex object to "select" one of the options, not just a number. So, once your `$http` call has returned, find the item in the list with the id you want and assign your scope variable to be the entire student object:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'ajax/getStudents',
  data: { teacherId: 0 }
}).success(function (result) {
    $scope.students = result;

    angular.forEach($scope.students, function(student) {
      if (student.id == 4) {
        $scope.selectedStudent = student;
      }
    });
});
```

If you add the `as` statement to your `ng-repeat` you can select the student by id like so:

```
<select ng-options="option.id as option.fname+' '+option.lname for option in students track by option.id"
           class="form-control"
           name="studentId"
           ng-model="selectedStudent"
           id="studentId"
           ng-change="loadStudent()"
           >
           <option value="">Please choose a student</option>
       </select>

$scope.selectedStudent = { id: 4 };
```

I prefer to use lodash or underscore to find an item in a list rather than using `forEach`:

```
$scope.selectedStudent = lodash.find($scope.students, { 'id': 4 });
```

Comment: Hello @joelCDoyle, thanks for replyiing.
What i'mve done is looping through every json object in the $http reply and comparing the student.id. 
I thaught though that what i'm doing is wrong (even if it works) as i read that the TRACK BY in the ng-options can be used to compare a specific object field with the number I want as preselected. 

for (var i = 0; i < $scope.students.length; i++){
    if(($scope.students[i].id) == $scope.preselectedStudent) { $scope.selectedStudent = $scope.students[i]; }
   }

Comment: Look at the official example on the `ngOptions` documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions